# How do I get the repeating sum for the entire column for each row in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the repeating company total for each row. There are various customers indicated in the first row and would like each row to get the sum. I have attached an imagine below for more clarification. [image]

I tried a bunch of various codes I found on stack without avail.

Comment: More than just using SUM?  You could add a column to hold the total for each row, and then do an INSERT statement to SUM each ROW and put that total into the column.
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp

Comment: I should have prefixed, TotalQtyShipped = SUM(Product_Qty) and Avg2Month =  SUM(Product_Qty)/2 .... they are not columns stored within the table

Comment: @easleyfixed how would the code look for that? I'm not sure I'm following all the way. I haven't used sql in a while and need to brush up on it

Comment: So what is the formula you want to be the running total?  Like Customer 91774 has 4 shipped, 2 average .. then what do we do with that?  But if you got the fomula of what you want to calculate you can run it in an insert statement to populate the new column.

Comment: Actually I just realized this would be an UPDATE not an INSERT .. Im use to making logs go into a different place, but basically UPDATE TABLENAME SET THING = THISVALUE WHERE thekeycolumnname = theactualkey .  Does that make sense?  and THIS VALUE would be replaced with the formula to calculate the running total

Comment: Oh wait .. wait .. you aren't wanting to put a new column in .. you want a tally at the END of each column? like total of the total quantity shipped?

Comment: Yes, but I believe I figured it out! SUM(Product_Qty) OVER()...This give me the repeating sum in each row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252578/discussion-between-danchdrezzing-and-easleyfixed).